# I am Receiving Error on Formula Number Field

Tags: lightning, lightning-experience, formula, formula-field

I am trying to create a formula based on some timestamp fields that will return a number. The error I am getting is "Syntax Error" without anymore details. Below is the formula I have entered.

I went off this article to get this code because it is exactly what I am looking for - https://opfocus.com/blog/how-to-accurately-track-salesforce-stage-changes/

```
IF( ISBLANK( PQ_Timestamp_v2__c ), NULL,
IF( NOT(ISBLANK( CFU_Timestamp_v2__c)) , CFU_Timestamp_v2__c – PQ_Timestamp_v2__c,
IF( NOT(ISBLANK( RFA_Timestamp__c )) , RFA_Timestamp__c – PQ_Timestamp_v2__c,
IF( NOT(ISBLANK( Ready_for_ETRAN_Timestamp_v2__c )) , Ready_for_ETRAN_Timestamp_v2__c – PQ_Timestamp_v2__c,
IF( NOT(ISBLANK( Audit_Timestamp__c )) , Audit_Timestamp__c – PQ_Timestamp_v2__c,
IF( NOT(ISBLANK( Bank_Handoff_Timestamp_v2__c )) , Bank_Handoff_Timestamp_v2__c – PQ_Timestamp_v2__c,
IF( NOT(ISBLANK( Declined_Timestamp_v2__c )) , Declined_Timestamp_v2__c – PQ_Timestamp_v2__c,
IF( NOT(ISBLANK( Withdrawn_Timestamp_v2__c )) , Withdrawn_Timestamp_v2__c – PQ_Timestamp_v2__c,
IF( IsClosed, Closed_Date__c – PQ_Date__c,
now() – PQ_Timestamp_v2__c )))))))))
```

Comment: If you can accept using a Report for this analysis, then consider using a “Opportunity History” report and manipulate its “From Stage”, “To Stage”, and “Stage Duration” within the filters, and groupings within a Summary Report

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue is your minus sign character (`-`).

I presume you copied this formula from that site and then replaced the fields. It seems the minus sign (`-`) is actually an [en dash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Hyphens_and_dashes) instead of a *hyphen-minus* which is causing the generic issue. You can copy and paste from that article or your formula into a [ASCII Text to Hex Code Converter](https://www.rapidtables.com/convert/number/ascii-to-hex.html) and see the difference when compared to typing on your keyboard.

| Source | What it looks like | Hex | Character |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Your linked article & this question | – | 2013 | en dash |
| Keyboard | - | 2D | hyphen-minus |

I suspected this after I had copied your formula exactly as is and received the same generic error when I should've received an `error: field xxxx doesn't exist`.

Reproduced this in my org by doing the following:

1. Copied your formula as is from this question
2. Replaced all fields with fields that actually exist in my org
3. Got the same generic error
4. Removed all en dashes (`-`) and re-typed them manually with my keyboard within the editor
5. Validated and got a *successful* compile

Comment: that was it!! thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Everything looks correct to me, but I went ahead and refactored this to see if this version might work:

```
IF(IsClosed,
    Closed_Date__c – PQ_Date__c,
    BLANKVALUE(
        CFU_Timestamp_v2__c,
        BLANKVALUE(
            RFA_Timestamp__c,
            BLANKVALUE(
                Ready_for_ETRAN_Timestamp_v2__c,
                BLANKVALUE(
                    Audit_Timestamp__c,
                    BLANKVALUE(
                        Bank_Handoff_Timestamp_v2__c,
                        BLANKVALUE(
                            Declined_Timestamp_v2__c,
                            BLANKVALUE(
                                Withdrawn_Timestamp_v2__c,
                                now()
                            )
                        )
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    ) - PQ_Timestamp_v2__c
)
```

It's not exactly the same as yours, but I think this might be more accurate?